# Constantly increasing memory usage when passing around huge arrays to webworker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, babylonjs

I am currently doing some 3d modeling using babylonjs. I need to create a pressure map from given pressure at specific points. I am doing that using [IDW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting). However this means that even with my map being a size of 70x90 grid requires me to have an array of 25200 (4 rgba values for each pixel) entries. Then this buffer is passed to a `RawTexture` for assigning it to a material, that is overlaid on the object

I am using a web worker, because I have to update the pressure values every 100ms and I don't want to block the main thread.The issue occurs when I am return that array (created in `calculate` function) from a service worker.

For some reason the memory usage just keeps going up, without stopping. It eventually goes up to around 1.5 gigabytes and I have to kill it.

**The question** : Is there any way to prevent this and what could be causing such high memory usage?

Worker:

```
// @flow
import { find, propEq, both } from 'ramda';
import { colorFromValue } from './color';
import { inverseDistance, distanceValues } from './math';

const findPoint = (x: number, y: number) =>
  find(both(propEq('x', x), propEq('y', y)));

const distanceDict = {};

/* eslint-disable */
function calculate(options: Object, pList: Array<*>) {
  const points = pList || [];
  const { height, width } = options;
  const gridWidth = width * 4;
  const grid = new Uint8Array(options.width * options.height * 4);

  for (let y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {
    const rW = y * gridWidth;
    for (let i = 0; i < gridWidth; i += 4) {
      const index = i + rW;
      const x = i / 4;
      const dictKey = `${x}--${y}`;
      let bottoms = distanceDict[dictKey];

      if (bottoms === undefined) {
        bottoms = distanceValues(points, x, y);
        distanceDict[dictKey] = bottoms;
      }
      const point = findPoint(x, y)(points);

      const value = point !== undefined && point !== null ?
        point.value : inverseDistance(points, bottoms);
      const color = colorFromValue(value);
      grid[index] = color[0];
      grid[index + 1] = color[1];
      grid[index + 2] = color[2];
      grid[index + 3] = 255;
    }
  }
  return grid;
}

self.onmessage = (e) => {
  const { points, options } = e.data;
  const grid = calculate(options, points);
  self.postMessage(grid.buffer, [grid.buffer]);
};
```

Painting:

```
modifyNodes = (points: Array<*>) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  this.worker.onmessage = (e) => {
    this._texture.update(new Uint8Array(e.data));
    res();
  } 
  const data = {
    options: this._options,
    points,
  };
  this.worker.postMessage(data);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

So it seems the issue was in the `colorFromValue` function that was memoized. Because the values had quite few decimal points it could create up to 9! new entries into cache, so it drove up the memory usage...